# Vue.js カスタムフィルタでhtmlタグを含んだ文字を返したい

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Vue.jsのカスタムフィルタを作成し、改行を`<br>`タグに変換したいのですが、どうやるのがいいでしょうか。

```html
<p>{{text | nl2br}}</p>
```

```js
Vue.filter('nl2br', value => value.replace(/\n/g, '<br>'));
```

これだと `"文字列<br>文字列"` のように、エスケープされた文字が表示されます。
以下のように、text全てエスケープしない、というのはやりたくありません。

```html
<p>{{{text | nl2br}}}</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

簡単にやるとすれば、filterを使わずに、そもそも改行させるようにcssを使ったほうが早いと思いますが、どうでしょうか？
これならば、タグはエスケープされないと思いますが。

```
<style>
p {
  white-space: pre;
}
</style>
```